# Everyday German. How to correctly order? Say, beer, pizza and ice cream

Tags: preposition

Three very little questions, which I think do not deserve to be considered separately:

At the restaurant:

1. You want a beer. It is `das Bier`, but one asks for a *Paulaner, Duvel,..., X-Marke*. It turns out that the brand could be a German substantive with intrinsic `die` or `der` article. Which of these do you ask?

   > a) *Ein großes `X-Marke`, bitte* or
   >   b) *Einen großen `X-Marke`, bitte.*
   >   (Here `X-Marke` stands for a masculin sustantive representing a beer brand)
2. You are about ordering a pizza (perhaps not the same day if you don't like it with beer) whose main ingredient is salami, and has some mushrooms. What do you say?

   > Ich hätte gerne eine große Pizza (`von/aus/keine oder andere Präposition`) Salami mit Pilzen.
3. Now you want an ice cream.

   > *Eine Kugel (`von/aus/keine oder andere Präposition`) Schokolade, bitte*

Comment: 1) Ein großes Paulaner/Weizen/Öttinger/... 2) eine große Pizza Salami mit ganz vielen Pilzen 3) 2 Kugeln im Hörnchen, einmal Schokolade und einmal Zitrone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In this case, the implied *Bier* dominates, so you’ll say:

   > Ein großes Weizen, bitte.
2. Often, pizzas are given sort of a name in the menu, and “Pizza Salami” is a common label. For this reason, you can indeed say:

   > Ich hätte gern eine große Pizza Salami mit Pilzen.

   This does not work in general, though; “Pizza Champignons” sounds strange, because the common label for this is “Pizza Funghi”. You could either make a composite word or list all ingredients with *mit*:

   > Ich hätte gern eine Salamipizza mit Pilzen./Ich hätte gern eine Champignonpizza.
   >   Ich hätte gern eine Pizza mit viel Salami und Pilzen.
3. Quantities are usually used without preposition, such as *ein Glas Wein*, *eine Portion Reis*, *ein Schälchen Erdbeeren*, *eine Prise Salz*, *zwei Zentner Kies*; so it is *eine Kugel Schokolade* as well (or *eine Kugel Schokoladeneis*, in case it is not clear already).

   Ice-cream sellers usually want to know beforehand how many scoops you are ordering and whether they should be in a cone or a paper cup (though cups often aren’t available for one or two scoops only). Thus, you could say:

   > Eine Kugel Schokolade (in der Waffel), bitte.
   >   Ich hätte gern drei Kugeln im Becher, und zwar Schokolade, Stracciatella und Banane.

   (Pronunciation note: *Stracciatella* is usually pronounced [ʃtʁatsjaˈtɛla].)

   As indicated in Em1’s comment, *Hörnchen* is an alternative to *Waffel*. According to *Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen* (2004), *Hörnchen* is used in the central and northwestern parts of Germany, *Eistüte* in Austria and large parts of Germany, *Cornet* in Switzerland, and *Stanitzel* in parts of Austria.

Comment: Just learned something. Didn't know that *Hörnchen* isn't said overall.

Comment: Two more practical additions: when ordering *"Weizen"* only you always will have to answer the following in the south of Germany *"Hefe? Hell oder dunkel?"*. Chocolate icecream will be short *"Eine Kugel Schoko"* rather than *"Schokolade"*.

Comment: ad 1) Also compare „Das König der Biere“ ;)

Comment: On the topic of *Hörnchen/Waffel/Tüte/Stanizel* see [the related question in German](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22969)

Comment: I think it is debatable what the _usual_ pronunciation of _Stracciatella_ in Germany is, and maybe we would need an ice cream seller to decide. But for learners we should at least add that the correct Italian (and even [recommended by Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stracciatella_Speiseeis)) pronunciation is [strat͜ʃaˈtɛla].

Comment: @Matthias: The Duden-recommended pronunciation is not the original Italian pronunciation, though, because both the second _t_ sound (from written _cci_) and the _l_ are geminated in Italian (i.e. held for a longer time). So one could say Duden gives a “Germanized” approximation of the Italian spoken word whereas many people in practice use a _spelling pronunciation_.

Comment: @chirlu Do you happen to know how to express this subtle difference in IPA notation? I don't know very much and thought the Duden entry was as close to the original as one could get with IPA. I also tried to look up an Italian source, but to no avail.

Comment: @Matthias: Often, geminated consonants are doubled ([strattʃaˈtɛlla]), even though this isn’t strictly correct nor unambiguous: For plosives at least, it could be mistaken to signify double release. The other option is to use the IPA length mark as in [stratːʃaˈtɛlːa]. Note that gemination is phonematic in Italian and some other languages such as Finnish, i.e. there are minimal pairs of words that only differ in consonant length.