# Wo sind die Eistüten hin?

Tags: word-choice, history, regional

Kaufe ich ein Berlin ein Eis, werde ich gefragt, ob ich es „im Becher oder in der Waffel“ möchte. Ich bin mir recht sicher, dass ich vor 30 Jahren nur gefragt wurde, ob ich einen „Becher oder eine Tüte“ möchte. Verwunderlich ist ein solcher Wandel nicht, denn außer den Migranten, die hier Deutsch lernen, haben wir immer mehr solche, die das Deutsch ihrer Heimat mitbringen. Daher meine Frage:

Wie ist die regionale Verbreitung von „Tüte“ und „Waffel“ in diesem Kontext, und wie hat sie sich in den letzten 50 Jahren entwickelt?

Comment: Better tags anyone? Danke.

Comment: Regional gibt es Eis auch im Hörnchen.

Comment: @Crissov, Danke, das wusste ich nicht, passt aber zur Form. Anderswo gibt es ja auch *cornetto*. Wo sagt man „Hörnchen“?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ich weiß von Hörnchen einmal in Rheinhessen (Mainz-Alzey) andererseits von ner westfälischen Freundin aus Bocholt (fast schon Niederrhein, aber Bocholt hat ja angeblich die größte Kirmes Westfalens – nicht die im Münsterland, da würde ja Münster dazugehören. Regionalpatriotismus etc.) Tüte hab ich weder in Rheinhessen noch in Bayern je gehört.

Comment: Hörnchen?? Das sind doch Nudeln! Zumindest in Österreich: http://www.austriansupermarket.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/R/E/REC1007_7.jpg
Wer will Eis in Nudeln?

Comment: Welche Migranten? Die Sachsen und Schwaben? Eiverbibscht!

Answer (score 4):

Im Schwäbischen<sup>(1)</sup> gibt es keine "Tüten" - nur Taschen oder "Gucken" (was *nichts* mit "schauen" zu tun hat), aber die haben meistens einen oder zwei Henkel und sind aus Stoff, Papier oder Kunststoff<sup>(2)</sup> und zum Transport von Einkäufen gedacht.

Eis kenne ich ausschließlich "aus der **Waffel**" oder "aus dem Becher".

<sup>(2)</sup> Die sind allerdings so "modern", auch in sprachlicher Hinsicht, dass sie durchaus Plastik*tüten* heißen dürfen ;-)

---

<sup>(1)</sup><sup>*...und schon steht die Stephie mit einem Bein im [Fettnäpfchen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwabenhass) - Danke, Herr Thierse*</sup>

Comment: Ja, euch hatte ich mit im Sinn, als ich die Zugereisten erwähnte. Danke für das Vorwegnehmen eines zu offensichtlichen Kommentars dazu ;) Habt ihr gar keine Tüten?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... also wenn ich mal an Freundeskreis' erstes Album denke, da waren auf jeden Fall Tüten im Spiel, von dem her...

Comment: Zur regionalen Verteilung von Plastiktüte siehe http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f13b/

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Also *diese* Tüten, die von manchen als Teil der Freizeitgestaltung angezündet werden, haben die Schwaben auch, da haben wir (wie bei der Plastik*tüte*) das Wort übernommen. Meine Theorie: beide Arten Tüte sind ungefähr gleichzeitig populär geworden, nämlich in den späten 60ern oder den 70ern. Sobald das Ding aber nicht aus Plastik oder grasgefüllt ist, heißt es wieder "Tasche".

Answer (score 1):

### Wien:

Früher (vor ca. 1995 oder 2000): Stanitzel
Heute: Tüte

Comment: Kurz und knackig beantwortet, aber wie du weißt, bevorzugt GLU.SE längere Antworten. Magst du deine Antwort ein bisschen ausbauen?

Comment: Schön, das Stanitzel bezieht sich wie die Tüte auf die Kegelform.